# How to upgrade rails app from 2.2.2 to 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed rails.2.3.11 and run rake rails:upgrade.

Do i need to modify anymore files ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Steps for upgrading Rails 2.2.2 to 2.3.11.

1. `rails install -v=2.3.11`
2. modify `config/environment.rb`

   ```
   RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
   ```
3. run rake task => `rake rails:update # Update configs, scripts and javascripts`

   This rake task will modify some of the files.
4. modify `config/environment.rb`

   **Replace**

   ```
   config.action_controller.session = {
     :session_key => '_name_session',
     :secret      => 'asdfasfasfafafafadaseerweewr'
   }
   ```

   **with**

   ```
   config.action_controller.session = {
     :key => '_name_session',
     :secret      => 'asdfasfasfafafafadaseerweewr'
   }
   ```
5. modify `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

   **Replace**

   ```
   session :session_key => '_intrado_session_id'
   ```

   **with**

   ```
   #session :session_key => '_intrado_session_id'
   ```
6. **Replace**

   ```
   session.session_id
   ```

   **with**

   ```
   request.session_options[:id]
   ```

May be this will help...

**EDIT:**

Rails 2.3.11 + Rack 1.0.0 + Phusion Passenger 2.0.6 causing problem **500 internal server error undefined method 'rewind'** to solve that issue.

I have installed.

1. `sudo gem install rack -v=1.1.1`
2. `sudo gem install passenger -v=2.2.8`
3. `passenger-install-apache2-module`

It would prompt you to replace few lines in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf with the following at the end of installation of the 3nd step

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.8/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.8
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

This file would already have above three lines. So, it would be sufficient to replace 2.0.6 with 2.2.8.

After performing the above steps, restart apache2 and restart rails by the following commands.

1. `sudo /etc/init.d/http.d restart`
2. `cd /var/www/project_name`
3. `sudo touch tmp/restart.txt`

Comment: Possibly not the only issues you will run into, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Do not replace **session.session_id** with **request.session_options[:id]**.

It will lead to **500 internal server error**

I got **undefined local variable or method `request' for #**, when I replaced **session.session_id** with **request.session_options[:id]**.